# django listing all debts of customers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the django-rest framework.
I have a list called customers. (customers)
and I have a table where I add the debts of the customer.

I want to make a separate inquiry screen and list the debts of all customers.
api / debtlist form

a customer can have more than one debt record.
therefore, I want to show the total debt, total received and remaining debt amounts of each customer in a single line.

How can I do this?

[image]
[image]

Customer Model

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    created_userKey = models.UUIDField(editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    customerKey = models.UUIDField(editable=False, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    customerName = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    customerSurname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    customerIdentityNo = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=False)  # , unique=True)
    customerGender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')))
    customerPhone = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=False)
    customerBirth = models.DateField(blank=True)
    customerDescription = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    customerStatus = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    createdDate = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modifiedDate = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)
    modifiedByUser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='modifiedBy')
```

Debt.py

```
class Debt(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0,
                             blank=False) 
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False,
                                 related_name='customer') 
    debtKey = models.UUIDField(editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4,
                               blank=False)  
    createduserKey = models.UUIDField(editable=False,
                                      default=uuid.uuid4)
    totalDebt = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    receivedAmount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    paymentDate = models.DateField(blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    createdDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    modifiedDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Views.py

```
class DebtListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DebtCreateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        result = Debt.objects.values('customer__customerKey').annotate(Sum('totalDebt'), Sum('receivedAmount'))
        return result
```

Serializer

```
class DebtCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Debt
        fields = [
            'id',
            'user',
            'customer',
            'debtKey',
            'createduserKey',
            'totalDebt',
            'receivedAmount',
            'paymentDate',
            'description',
            'createdDate'
        ]
```

Comment: What query you have tried?

Comment: Show your models.

Comment: I'm afraid that "How can I do this?" is a way too broad question.

Comment: But you're storing total debt and received amount as strings. Why are you doing that? It will make it impossible to do what you want. Why aren't you storing them as integers or decimals?

Comment: fields edited as "DecimalField"

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the alternative for sql `GROUP BY` with `SUM()`. Which in Django ORM is the `.annotate()` function.

First of as @daniel suggested all storing them as string is incorrect, I suggest to use a numerical field (int,decimal,float)

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

result=Debt.objects.values('customer__customerKey').annotate(Sum('totalDebt'),Sum('receivedAmount'))
```

To implement this in the ListApiView you do not need a serializer. You can override the get method directly, so your view will become:

```py
class DebtListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DebtCreateSerializer

    def get(self):
        result=Debt.objects.values('customer__customerKey').annotate(Sum('totalDebt'),Sum('receivedAmount'))
    return Response(result)
```

This should work without calling the serializer. make sure you have the right imports.

Comment: ERROR Code;  KeyError at /api/debt/borc
"Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `customer` on serializer `DebtCreateSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'customer'."

Comment: Two things. 1)Can you try my suggestion in a shell to make sure this is what you want.
2) I believe this error because the serializer does not know how to interpret the user model. try adding the following in the Customer Model.
`def __str__(self):
    return self.customerName`

Comment: yes I've added code that you call in the customer model. error continues

Comment: I used the following snippet in view. is it correct ?

`
class DebtListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DebtCreateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        result = Debt.objects.values('customer__customer_id').annotate(Sum('totalDebt'), Sum('receivedAmount'))
        return result
`

Comment: I dont see a reason why you would override the `get_queryset` as such. The serializer as you defined would not know how to serialize the returned result

Answer (score 0):

a customer has more than one debt. o How can we see the total debt and remaining debt of the customer?

So customer A has 10 debt records.
How can we make total debt and remaining debt in one line?

```
id  customerName  customerKey  totalDebt  receivedAmount
1   joshn         84aa5d444d6  100        30
2   joshn         84aa5d444d6  95         20
3   max           32as5dd1d1d  60         40
4   william       8888888888a  800        150
5   william       8888888888a  65         15
```

I want to get a result like this

result:

```
id  customerName  customerKey  totalDebt  receivedAmount
1   joshn         84aa5d444d6  195        50
3   max           32as5dd1d1d  60         40
4   william       8888888888a  865        165
```